# Bidirectional static value mapping in c++17

Tags: c++, static, mapping, c++17

I want to efficiently bidirectionally map some values of different types in C++17 (1:1 mapping of only very few values). Consider for example mapping enum values and integers, though the problem is applicable to other types as well. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
#include <optional>

enum class ExampleEnum { A, B, C, D, E };

class MyMapping {
public:
    std::optional<int> enumToInt(ExampleEnum v) {
        switch(v) {
        case ExampleEnum::A:
            return 1;
        case ExampleEnum::B:
            return 5;
        case ExampleEnum::D:
            return 42;
        }
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    std::optional<ExampleEnum> intToEnum(int v) {
        switch(v) {
        case 1:
            return ExampleEnum::A;
        case 5:
            return ExampleEnum::B;
        case 42:
            return ExampleEnum::D;
        }
        return std::nullopt;
    }
};
```

This has the obvious disadvantage of having to write everything twice, and forgetting to update one of the functions will lead to inconsistencies. Is there a better method?

I need:

- Consistency. It shouldn't be possible to have different semantics in mapping and reverse mapping.
- Compile-time definition. The values which are mapped are known in advance, and will not change at runtime.
- Runtime lookup. Which values will be looked up is not known at compile-time, and may even not contain a mapping at all (returning an empty optional instead).

I would like to have:

- No additional memory allocations
- Basically the same performance as the double-switch-method
- An implementation which makes the mapping definition easily extendable (i.e. adding more values in the future or applying it to other types)

Comment: Do you require 1::1 mapping or 1::Many ?

Comment: `switch`-ing is probably not going to be very effective if you add a lot of values. You'll search through half of them to find your match. Perhaps an `unordered_map` would be better?

Comment: One `std::unordered_map<int, enum>` and one  `std::unordered_map<enum, int>` should do it.

Comment: 1:1 mapping, and there won't be a a lot of values, so search time is not that critical. unordered_maps impose a lot of additional heap allocations and memory usage for such a simple use case, which I'd like to avoid

Comment: How big is the range of values? Two pllain arrays can be a very efficient way to do the lookup if the ranges between the smallest and the largest value aren't very big so they take up too much memory.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the range of values is small, typically sequential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've given a shot to very naive and simple implementation. https://godbolt.org/z/MtcHw8

```
#include <optional>
enum class ExampleEnum { A, B, C, D, E };


template<typename Enum, int N>
struct Mapping
{
    Enum keys[N];
    int values[N];

    constexpr std::optional<Enum> at(int x) const noexcept
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if(values[i] == x) return keys[i];
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    constexpr std::optional<int> at(Enum x) const noexcept
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if(keys[i] == x) return values[i];
        return std::nullopt;
    }
};

constexpr Mapping<ExampleEnum, 3> mapping{{ExampleEnum::A, ExampleEnum::B, ExampleEnum::D},
                                         {111, 222, 333}};

int main()
{
    int x = rand(); // Force runtime implementation
    auto optEnum = mapping.at(x);
    if(optEnum.has_value())
        return *mapping.at(ExampleEnum::B); // Returns 222, (asm line 3) constexpr works

    auto y = (ExampleEnum)rand(); // Force runtime implementation
    auto optInt = mapping.at(y);
    if(optInt.has_value())
        return (int)*mapping.at(333); // Returns 3, constexpr works

    return 0;
}
```

It utilizes loop unrolling to achieve switch-method performance in `int -> ExampleEnum` mappings.

Assembly for `ExampleEnum -> int` mapping is quite obscure, as optimizer utilized the fact that enum values are sequenced and prefers jump table over `if-else` implementation.

Anyway, the interface requires no duplication, just create `constexpr` object with two arrays fed into construction. You can have multiple mappings for same types. Also, `enum` type is templated.

Also, it can be easily extended to support two `enum class` instead of only `enum`-`int`.

I've also created snipped with raw switch implementations for assembly comparison:
https://godbolt.org/z/CbEcnZ

PS. I believe syntax `constexpr Mapping<ExampleEnum, 3> mapping` could be simplified with proper template deduction guide, but I have not found out how to do it.

PPS. I went with `N` up to 15, loop unrolling is still on: https://godbolt.org/z/-Cpmgm

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to avoid such code. They tend to violate one of the fundamental principles of software development, [The Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

You can improve `MyMapping` by making it general. Let a higher level class/function define the mappings.

```
class MyMapping {
   public:
      void registerItem(ExampleEnum eValue, int intValue)
      {
         enumToIntMap[eValue] = intValue;
         intToEnumMap[intValue] = eValue;
      }

      std::optional<int> enumToInt(ExampleEnum v) {
         auto iter = enumToIntMap.find(v);
         if ( iter != enumToIntMap.end() )
         {
            return iter->second;
         }
         else
         {
            return std::nullopt;
         }
      }

      std::optional<ExampleEnum> intToEnum(int v) {
         auto iter = intToEnumMap.find(v);
         if ( iter != intToEnumMap.end() )
         {
            return iter->second;
         }
         else
         {
            return std::nullopt;
         }
      }

      std::map<ExampleEnum, int> enumToIntMap;
      std::map<int, ExampleEnum> intToEnumMap;
};
```

A higher level function can be:

```
void initMyMapping(MyMapping& mapping)
{
   mapping.registerItem(A, 1);
   mapping.registerItem(B, 2);
   mapping.registerItem(D, 42);
}
```

I understand that this still violates the open-closed principle but to a lesser degree. If you want to add mapping data for `C` and `E`, you'll have to add code for that. However, you can do that without changing `MyMapping`. You also have the option of doing that in a second function, and not change `initMyMapping`.

```
void initMyMapping_extend(MyMapping& mapping)
{
   mapping.registerItem(C, 22);
   mapping.registerItem(E, 38);
}
```

Comment: This solution is great if a mapping should be constructed at runtime, but I'd like to avoid additional memory usage (like `std::map`), as the mapping is known at compile-time. It's also possible to introduce inconsistencies (`mapping.register(C, 22); mapping.register(C, 23)`) but that should be rather easy to fix

Comment: @Cybran, I understand your concerns. You'll have to weigh the pros and cons. Memory vs Maintainability.  Pick what makes sense for your application.